# How to install xpdf on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

I was trying to install *EPrints* on my *Ubuntu 20.04 desktop* but it lacked the dependency package **xpdf**. I have tried multiple ways to install it but failed.

Could anyone please tell me how to install it .

Comment: Does this help?  https://wiki.eprints.org/w/Installing_EPrints_on_Debian/Ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

xpdf was dropped from Ubuntu after 19.10. It's upstream development has slowed, the Debian package maintainer lost interest, and much of the functionality was replaced (and improved) by poppler, which is in 20.04.

1. Please file an upstream bug with eprints so they will change their dependency. That doesn't help you much today, but will make a huge difference in the future.
2. Try using the the 19.10 xpdf package. It's not guaranteed, but much better than nothing.

   - Get the package from http://packages.ubuntu.com.
   - Install using `sudo apt install /path/to/filename.deb`

Comment: How is poppler used as a PDF viewer? Which is the command line application to replace xpdf?

Comment: I have the same question, how do you use `poppler`, the web seems remarkably silent on this question.      I installed `libpoppler-dev` but still there's no `poppler` script

Answer (score 12):

You can manually download XPDF from the Ubuntu 18.04 default repository and install it with the below commands.

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/poppler/libpoppler73_0.62.0-2ubuntu2.14_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libpoppler73_0.62.0-2ubuntu2.14_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xpdf/xpdf_3.04-7_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./xpdf_3.04-7_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 4):

After some research, first failing to get xpdf to build or install, then evaluating some competitors, I found that **okular** is quite a good alternative. It's fast and the interface is more modern and comprehensive than others.

Of the installation choices:

- `sudo apt install okular`
- `sudo snap install okular`

apt wanted to install 185 packages and dependencies totaling 184 MB. I chose the snap because it's 70 MB and self-contained.

okular maintains the settings pretty well across invocations. It has a `--qwindowgeometry` option that works like `xpdf --geometry`.

Other tools (pdftotext, etc) are already there in poppler-utils.

Answer (score 0):

**Complete XPDF 3.04 installation process on Ubuntu 20.04 (Server LTS, in my case)!**

As taught by @N0rbert you can manually download XPDF from Ubuntu 19.10 repository and install it.

The scheme below teaches you how to install XPDF 3.04 with all its dependencies on Ubuntu 20.04...

```
cd /usr/local/src
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/poppler/libpoppler73_0.62.0-2ubuntu2.12_amd64.deb # Pack upload in repo 2020-11-26 18:08.
apt-get install ./libpoppler73_0.62.0-2ubuntu2.12_amd64.deb
rm -f ./libpoppler73_0.62.0-2ubuntu2.12_amd64.deb

cd /usr/local/src
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/poppler/poppler-utils_0.62.0-2ubuntu2.12_amd64.deb # Pack upload in repo 2020-11-26 18:08.
apt-get install ./poppler-utils_0.62.0-2ubuntu2.12_amd64.deb
rm -f ./poppler-utils_0.62.0-2ubuntu2.12_amd64.deb

cd /usr/local/src
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gsfonts-x11/gsfonts-x11_0.24_all.deb # Pack upload in repo 2015-12-31 05:14.
apt-get install ./gsfonts-x11_0.24_all.deb
rm -f ./gsfonts-x11_0.24_all.deb

cd /usr/local/src
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/cups-common_2.3.3-3ubuntu1_all.deb # Pack upload in repo 2020-09-04 18:13.
apt-get install ./cups-common_2.3.3-3ubuntu1_all.deb
rm -f ./cups-common_2.3.3-3ubuntu1_all.deb

cd /usr/local/src
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/libcups2_2.3.3-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb # Pack upload in repo 2020-09-04 18:13.
apt-get install ./libcups2_2.3.3-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
rm -f ./libcups2_2.3.3-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb

cd /usr/local/src
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/cups-client_2.3.3-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb # Pack upload in repo 2020-09-04 18:13.
apt-get install ./cups-client_2.3.3-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
rm -f ./cups-client_2.3.3-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb

cd /usr/local/src
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/cups-bsd_2.3.3-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb # Pack upload in repo 2020-09-04 18:13.
apt-get install ./cups-bsd_2.3.3-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
rm -f ./cups-bsd_2.3.3-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb

cd /usr/local/src
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xpdf/xpdf_3.04-7_amd64.deb # Pack upload in repo 2018-03-06 20:18.
apt-get install ./xpdf_3.04-7_amd64.deb
rm -f ./xpdf_3.04-7_amd64.deb
```

**Done!
Thanks! =D**